# Content_tag/Safe_join to replace html_safe being used in Rails helper involving iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video that a user is submitting. In my view I have the following:

```
<%= raw(youtube_embed(@region.youtube_url))%>
```

`youtube_url` is a string that is being submitted. So I created a helper to handle the input and regex:

```
module VideosHelper
 YOUTUBE_REGEX = %r(^(http[s]*:\/\/)?(www.)?(youtube.com|youtu.be)\/(watch\?v=){0,1}([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11}))

 def youtube_embed(url, width = '100%', height = '350px')
  youtube_id = find_youtube_id(url)

  result = %(<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="#{width}"
            height="#{height}" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/#{ youtube_id }"
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>)
  result.html_safe
end

def find_youtube_id(url)
  url = sanitize(url).to_str

  matches = YOUTUBE_REGEX.match url

  matches[6] || matches[5] if matches
 end
end
```

It loads but it's failing tests because I used `html_safe`. I've tried switching to the following:

```
 content_tag(:iframe, '', src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{youtube_id}" width: "#{width}" height: "#{height}" frameborder: 0 allowfullscreen )
```

But this results with the page failing and giving me the following errors:

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' m/embed/#{ youtube_id }"

Am I close with the `content_tag` or is there something better I should be using?

EDIT:
Attempted with answer posted below and get bad component(expected relative path component): /embed/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hY7m5jj9mM URI::InvalidComponenetError. It points specifically to uri.path += id.

So I actually switched some of the code to the following:

```
def youtube_embed(url, **kwargs)
 uri = URI("//www.youtube.com/embed/")
 uri.path
 uri += url
```

Removes the error but page loads nothing. Console displays "Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?stuff' in a frame because it is set X-Frame-Options to sameorigin.

Additional EDIT:
Tried with the following:

```
 def youtube_embed(url, **kwargs)
  uri = URI("//www.youtube.com/embed/")

  uri.path += find_youtube_id(url)
  options = {
   src: uri.to_s,
   width: '100%',
   height: '350px',
   frameborder: 0,
   allowfullscreen: true
 }
```

uri.path += find_youtube_id(url) results in "no implicit conversion of Array into String"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Ruby Standard Lib [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/InvalidURIError.html) and [CGI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html) modules instead of a regular expression when parsing URLs:

```
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'
module VideosHelper
  # use keyword arguments instead of positional arguments
  # when the order is not self apparent!
  def youtube_embed(url, **kwargs)
    uri = URI("//www.youtube.com/embed/")
    # @todo deal with nil value due to invalid input
    uri.path += find_youtube_id(url)
    # these are the default values
    options = {
      src: uri.to_s,
      width: '100%', 
      height: '350px',
      frameborder: 0,
      allowfullscreen: true
    }
    # see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag
    content_tag(:iframe, nil, options.merge(kwargs), false)
  end

  def find_youtube_id(url)
    begin 
      uri = URI(url)
      CGI.parse(uri.query).try(:[], "v").try(:first)
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
      # @todo handle bad user input
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nicely pointed to the documentation, but did you see "Note: this is legacy syntax, see tag method description for details." ? Use http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag instead.

Comment: @JohanWentholt Are you sure thats relevant for `content_tag` and not just `tag` which has a different signature?

Comment: bad component(expected relative path component)

Comment: @Jake where does the error occur and whats the input?

Comment: Ah, I missed that you where passing the whole url and not just the id to the embed method. Edited.

Comment: "no implicit conversion of Array into String" uri.path += find_youtube_id(url)

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @max. Actual answer:

```
module VideosHelper
 def youtube_embed(url, **kwargs)
  uri = URI("//www.youtube.com/embed/")
  uri.path += find_youtube_id(url).join("','")
  options = {
    src: uri.to_s,
    width: '100%',
    height: '350px',
    frameborder: 0,
    allowfullscreen: true
  }
  content_tag(:iframe, nil, options.merge(kwargs), false)
 end

def find_youtube_id(url)
  begin 
    uri = URI(url)
    CGI.parse(uri.query).try(:[], "v")
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
   nil
  end
end
end
```